# Access main window from a NSDocument class

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsdocument

I have a NSDocument class, where I'd need to access the main menu window, the one that gets opened when the app start. When I operate in that window from the app all seems to work, but when trying to do the same operations from `readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:` the window I access seems to be nil. Why this happens?

#### EDIT: Some code which deals with this:

```
- (BOOL)readFromFileWrapper:(NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapper ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    if([[NSFileManager alloc] fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Project.plist",[[self fileURL] path]]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [[self fileURL] path]);

        NSDictionary *project = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Project.plist",[[self fileURL] path]]];

        if([[project objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"vote"]) {

            [self openProject:[[self fileURL] path] type:@"vote"];

            return YES;

        } else if([[project objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"quiz"]) {

            [self openProject:[[self fileURL] path] type:@"quiz"];

            return YES; 

        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

That is my `readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:` method. Here is my `openProject:type:` method:

```
-(void)openProject:(NSString *)filepath type:(NSString *)type 
{
    NSLog(@"Opening project @ %@",filepath);
    NSLog(@"%@", [MainWindow description]);
    [projectDesignerView setFrame:[[[[MainWindow contentView] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] frame]];
    [projectDesignerToolbar setFrame:[MainWindow frame] display:FALSE];
    [[MainWindow contentView] replaceSubview:[[[MainWindow contentView] subviews]objectAtIndex:0] with:projectDesignerView];
    [[projectDesignerToolbar toolbar] setShowsBaselineSeparator:YES];
    [MainWindow setToolbar:[projectDesignerToolbar toolbar]];
    [MainWindow setRepresentedFilename:filepath];
    [MainWindow setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [[filepath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension], [projectDesignerToolbar title]]];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"projectDesigner" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [[projectDesignerWebview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

`NSLog(@"%@", [MainWindow description]);` returns nil, when `MainWindow` should be the Main App Window. I think the problem is that double-clicking on a file reallocs all, and hence is failing.

Comment: Please post your code so we can understand exactly what you're doing that's not working right.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what code to post exactly. I'll try

Comment: Any clues with the code I just posted?

Comment: Where do you initialize/setup `MainWindow`?  

Also, `MainWindow` probably should be called `mainWindow`. It's bad style to capitalize variable names. Class names (e.g. NSString) are usually capitalized. It makes your code difficult to read and follow when you capitalize variable names, because it makes them look like class names.

Comment: MainWindow is a outlet connected to a Window in MainMenu.xib. About naming, yeah I think it'd be better calling so, but wrote it in a rush and didn't had time to change it :)

Comment: I've posted an answer that I hope helps. The point about naming the MainWindow outlet is pretty important though, so it would be a good idea to change it. Code style isn't something the compiler complains about, but it is an important part of being a good programmer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. You mention that `MainWindow` is an outlet in `MainMenu.xib` but you don't specify what class is defining the outlet.

If this window is designed to have a single main "project" window then you should assign the outlet property in your application delegate.

You can then access this from other classes using something like `[(YourAppDelegate*)[NSApp delegate] mainWindow];`.

If, however, you are trying to obtain a reference to the window of the current document then it's a little bit more complicated.

The reason that `NSDocument` does not have a `window` outlet by default is that it is designed to work with instances of `NSWindowController` that themselves manage the various windows related to the document. This is so a document can have multiple windows showing different views of the same data, additional palettes related to the document and so on. Each instance of `NSWindowController` would have its own window nib file and `window` outlet.

By default, `NSDocument` creates a single instance of `NSWindowController` for you if you do not specifically create and assign `NSWindowController` instances to the document. This is automatic, you don't need to even know the window controller exists.

That means that if you aren't managing your document windows with `NSWindowController` instances yourself, you can get the window attached to the `NSWindowController` that is automatically-created by `NSDocument` like so:

```
/* Only implement this in an NSDocument instance where the 
   automatic window controller is being used.
   If the document has multiple window controllers, you must
   keep track of the main window controller yourself
   and return its window
*/
- (NSWindow*)documentWindow
{
    if([[self windowControllers] count] == 1)
    {
        return [[[self windowControllers] firstObject] window]; 
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to handle this is to add an IBOutlet to your NSDocument subclass, then hook it up to the document window in the .xib file.

In your .h:

```
@interface MyDocument : NSDocument

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *docWindow;

@end
```

In your .m:

```
@implementation MyDocument : NSDocument

@synthesize docWindow;

@end
```

Then, the most important part, open up MyDocument.xib (or whatever it's called), and drag a connection from File's Owner (assuming that's your NSDocument subclass, which it is by default) to the main document window, and hook it up to the docWindow outlet.

Comment: If you've really done this and it's not working, I'm afraid I can't say what's wrong without seeing more of your code and/or your .xib file(s).